Solving an inequality with $3$ variables.
I am trying to prove the following inequality:
$$\frac{xy+z-1+\sqrt{(xy-z+1)^2+4y(z-1)}}{2} \ge \frac{(y-x)(z-1)}{y-x-1}.$$
Here we know that $y \ge x+2$ and $x,y,z$ are positive integers.
I tried simplifying a bit and then squaring both sides, but it is getting messed up.
After simplifying I got:
$$\sqrt{(xy-z+1)^2+4y(z-1)} \ge \frac{(y-x+1)(z-1)}{y-x-1} - xy.$$
After this, I was trying to square both sides, but it is getting messy!
Maybe we can rename $z-1=p$ and it will look a bit simpler:
$$\sqrt{(xy-p)^2+4yp} \ge \frac{(y-x+1)p}{y-x-1} - xy.$$
Can someone give some hints on how to proceed with this?
Thanks.

The inequality does not hold when $x=1,y=3$ and $z=5$ for which $LHS=7$ and $RHS=8$.

Can you find an example with $x>1$? @mathlove

Yes, $(x,y,z)=(2,4,8)$ is a counterexample.

Maybe typos? For example, if the LHS is of the form $\frac{-B+\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$ (the bigger solution of a quadratic equation), there should be a typo in either $xy+z-1$ or $(xy-z+1)^2$ ?

@mathlove thanks, I think the inequality is not true, the counterexamples are sufficient.
